# Django: only CSS is not served by Nginx

Tags: html, css, django, nginx, static

I deployed my Django app on a VPS with Nginx and I want Nginx to handle the statics. The strange thing right now is that all the images are rendered properly, but the CSS is not working at all...

Django setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

Nginx configure:

```
location /static/{
    alias /home/xxx/App/django_app/static_root/;
}
```

In html template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app1/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all">

<img src="{% static 'app1/images/page1_img1.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

I've run `python manage.py collectstatic`, set `Debug = False` (everything works fine when Debug is true).

I can confirm that all images are located in `/home/xxx/App/django_app/static_root/app1/images`, while all css files are under `/home/xxx/App/django_app/static_root/app1/css`.

I'm able to access the css file with the url `https://myserver/static/app1/css/style.css`, also there is no error message in Nginx log.

I've tried different browsers, cleared cache, restarted the server and Nginx several times with no luck, really running out of idea... Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to validate your css and  html markup. also take a look at collectstatic output - where exactly style.css comes from.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I verified the css file with an online validator and no notable error is reported. The output of collectstatic only shows the number of static files copied, nothing else.

Comment: If you can navigate css file url manually then this is not about static files config for sure. Show any style definition and corresponding template part.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Well, my own css might be problematic, but the thing is that even the django admin page doesn't render css at all... Those css files are collected by collectstatic and I'm pretty sure I never modified them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved by adding `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` to nginx config file...

Comment: This is so odd. I've set up many of these but have never run into this issue before. Thanks for including it here!